# How to make SQlite async in UWP?

Tags: c#, sqlite, asynchronous, uwp, task

I'm fairly new to databases and asynchronous programing. I'm making a POS app that will eventually have hundreds of customers and possibly thousands of transactions. When I want to do a customer search or look up a previous ticket I don't want my program to hang waiting on the results.

Here is the method that shows the search result:

```
 private void searchCritiria_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        FilteredCustomer.Clear();
        if(searchCritiria.Text.Length >= 3)
        {
            SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Customers.db");
            string sSQL = null;

                sSQL = @"SELECT [first],[last],[spouse],[home],[work],[cell] FROM Customers";
                ISQLiteStatement dbState = dbConnection.Prepare(sSQL);

            while (dbState.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
            {
                string sFirst = dbState["first"] as string;
                string sLast = dbState["last"] as string;
                string sSpouse = dbState["spouse"] as string;
                string sHome = dbState["home"] as string;
                string sWork = dbState["work"] as string;
                string sCell = dbState["cell"] as string;
                //Load into observable collection
                if (searchType.SelectedIndex == 0)//name search
                {
                    if(sFirst.Contains(searchCritiria.Text) || sLast.Contains(searchCritiria.Text) || sSpouse.Contains(searchCritiria.Text))
                    FilteredCustomer.Add(new Customer {first = sFirst, last = sLast, spouse = sSpouse, home = sHome, work = sWork, cell = sCell});
                }
                else//number search
                {
                    if(sWork.Contains(searchCritiria.Text)|| sHome.Contains(searchCritiria.Text) || sCell.Contains(searchCritiria.Text))
                    FilteredCustomer.Add(new Customer { first = sFirst, last = sLast, spouse = sSpouse, home = sHome, work = sWork, cell = sCell });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Throughout my program I have void methods that are structured similar to this.

I'm not sure how to solve this issue. I tried doing some research but no success. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use `await Task.Run(()=>{});` which will run the code inside async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

As correctly pointed out by @AndriyK, the answer would not have made your code `asynchronous`.

**What it means:**
Although the code works and you're able to push in data, if in case you reach a condition where two threads are trying to write into the database (`Database is Locked` condition, your application would still freeze until the database is not locked anymore or it times out. This means any loaders running would also freeze.

---

### Making it `asynchronous`

To do so, you must run your `SQLite` code in a `Task.Run()` block. This would ensure your database runs on a different `Thread` and ensure your UI would never hang. This would also allow you to show `ProgressRing` (or other loaders) to the user while the application waits for the database to unlock. Below is the code:

```
public void PerformSQLTasks()
{
    // your SQL code code here!  
}
```

and run the above code by using:

```
Task.Run(() => PerformSQLTasks());
// or even
Task.Run(PerformSQLTasks);
```

### Accepted Answer:

To make your UI not hang, you can make your method return a `Task` instead of void to make it `awaitable`. This will not make your code `async` but would allow the caller to `await` this method completion. To achieve this, follow the method signature below:

```
public Task PerformSQLTasks()
{
    // your code here!  
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

and you can call it by:

```
private async void searchCritiria_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
   await PerformSQLTasks();
}
```

> Remember this won't make your code `Asynchronous`

Comment: Thank you very much! I just edited the code and it compiled fine. I had to run so I will test it when I get home. If it works I will mark it as the correct answer. The task.completedTask was the peice I was missing. Thanks again

Comment: No problem. Do let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Worked like a charm!! I added 2000 customers with a for loop and the collection populated like in a snap!

Comment: Just changing method return type won't make it run asynchronously. It will still run blocking in same thread.

Comment: @AndriyK The question states that the UI thread must not block while it's processing. `ReturnType` was set to `Task` so that the method could be made `await`-able. This mean that although the code execution thread would wait till task is finished but UI thread would not wait. If you have a case where in you want to make it run `asynchronously` (the code thread must not wait either) your can look up `Threading` or even using `Dispatchers`. If you have a question posted I'll be more than happy to answer it. I don't understand the downvote though, the answer addresses the question's intent.

Comment: It's just flatly wrong. If you await method that has no asynchronous calls in it, it will block calling thread. Async/await is not making application multithreaded per se. If driver supports async calls, like MS SQL's, you can run e.g. await command.ExecuterReaderAsync(), but SQLite drivers don't, so you should use e.g. Task.Run() to kick it in separate thread manually.

Comment: @AndriyK In the question he's not looking for `multithreading` and hence I haven't added it as a part of the solution never the less feel free to edit the answer to add any missing content to the answer. You can also add an answer to the question for others who visit the question.